# display boxshadow like image

Tags: html, css

I want to make like this box shadow its from a psd file :
i have made a screenshot :

http://s3.postimg.org/k59bfo5s3/boxshadow.png

i don't know how i can make that by code of css

but my other idea  I thought also to extract the shadow from PSD file like that

and moove it to my html page but i don't know where i can place the code for image of shadow

http://jsfiddle.net/4pbq2tx8/11/

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset=utf-8>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/carousel.js"></script>
        <div id="carousel">
            <div class="title">title</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

css :

```
#carousel {
    border:solid 1px #1a1a1a;
    position:relative;
    width:903px;
    height:299px;
    margin:0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background:url(http://s22.postimg.org/l2e24m48x/light.png) ;
    /* my probleme is here */
    box-shadow: url(http://s14.postimg.org/7tmkd1hfl/shadow.png);
}

body {
    background-color: #c7c7c7;
}

.title {
    position:absolute;
    width:902px;
    height:47px;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    line-height: 47px;
    border:solid 0.5px #686868;
    background:url(http://s22.postimg.org/s4bzqt7up/title.png) bottom left repeat  ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1/

Try with that:

```
#carousel:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  bottom: -100px;
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: url('http://s14.postimg.org/7tmkd1hfl/shadow.png') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/4pbq2tx8/12/)

### 2/

If you want the shadow to be exact length of 1100px you need to change few things:

```
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 1100px;
}
.wrap:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -95px;
  z-index: 9999;
  content: " ";
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://s14.postimg.org/7tmkd1hfl/shadow.png') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

And wrap your `#carousel` in `.wrap`

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="carousel">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE WITH WRAPPER](http://jsfiddle.net/4pbq2tx8/15/)

Comment: thank you so mush its amazing  all works good but i don't understand the algorithm that you have followed in the second way wraping method and sorry for my question i am beginner why  content: " "; i cannot imagine how that works :D

Comment: i have deleted this line background-size: cover; and all still good

Answer (score 0):

Your shadow looks like a 3D object, so take advantage of that, and use a 3D pseudo element with a box shadow:

```
#carousel {
    -webkit-perspective: 500;
    -webkit-perspective-origin: 50% 50%;
}

#carousel:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    bottom: -45px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #888;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(80deg);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 15px #888;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pbq2tx8/16/)**

Tested on chrome. Should work on Safari too. For other browsers, you will need add their vendor prefixes, `-moz-`, `-ms-`.

Old browsers will not support 3D transformations, and that's ok. No shadow will appear.
http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/

Also, you don't need, and should not use images. You can replicate the same effect with linear gradients.

Comment: do you have tutorial for making that with  linear gradients ?

Comment: You can use this [online tool](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). You set the gradient and then simply copy&paste the generated CSS code.

Comment: @user3778154 Maybe this one too http://thesiteslinger.com/blog/photoshop-to-css-conversion-3-methods-compared/